# How to retrieve the right URL of a file uploaded (with spring MVC) on the server (Tomcat)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, upload

I have a form that allow user to upload an image (jpg), in order to show that image in another page.

This is the method I used:

```
public void salvaFoto(...) throws FotoUtilException{                
            ...
            String path = context.getRealPath("prova/1.jpg");
            File file = new File(path);     
            commonsMultipartFile.transferTo(file);
            ... 
}
```

It works.

The jpg is saved here: `D:\root backup\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringGestioneErrori\prova\1.jpg`, that is the url the I get with `context.getRealPath("prova/1.jpg")`

Now, I have problem printing that image.

I tried to find the image using again `context.getRealPath("prova/1.jpg")`, this way:

```
<img src="D:/root backup/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SpringGestioneErrori/prova/1.jpg">
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried also:

```
<img src="/SpringGestioneErrori/prova/1.jpg">
```

but it didn't work as well.

Thank you

Comment: just to clarify.. you want to print image on a client side printer. image that is stored on your server: D:/root.../ ?

Comment: Thank you. Anyway the problem seems to be about Spring or Eclipse or Tomcat. If I manually add a folder with an image to my project, under WebContent, I'm not able to reach it by typing the URL. It seems TomCat don't upgrade my web application directory.

Answer (score 1):

I am using local rootDirecotry instead. This is working fine for me.

String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
image.transferTo(new File(rootDirectory+"\images\"+ImageName.jpg"));

Then access it from same directory

```
<img src="<c:url value="/images/imageName.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you. Anyway the problem seems to be about Spring or Eclipse or Tomcat. If I manually add a folder with an image to my project, under WebContent, I'm not able to reach it by typing the URL. It seems TomCat don't upgrade my web application directory.